# Is this an integrating factor at all and why does it work?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I required some help for the differential equation: $y' = y\,\sin(x)+\sin(2\,x)$

I figured that it's not that easy to solve because of the integral $\int\frac{\sin(2\,x)}{e^{cos(x)}}\mathrm{d}x$ that is appearing in the premade formula.

However a kind user suggested me to multiply the particular solution $y_p = \sin(2\,x)$ with $e^{\cos(x)}$ and integrate afterward. As a result the integral becomes pretty handy. To be honest I recognized the beauty of this approach but didn't understand it yet - why this is functioning.
Can someone explain to me afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a general, linear, first order ODE:
\begin{equation}x'(t) + p(t)x(t) = f(t).\tag{1}\end{equation}
The idea is to multiply the equation by a function $y(t)$ such that $(1)$ becomes of the form:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\bigl(y(t)x(t)\bigr) = y(t)f(t) \tag{2}$$
Then assuming that you can express $\int y(t)f(t)dt$, you get your solution by integrating $(2)$.

The factor can be found by integrating $y'(t) = p(t)y(t)$. Indeed:
$$y(t)x'(t) + y(t)p(t)x(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\bigl(y(t)x(t)\bigr) - y'(t)x(t) + y(t)p(t)x(t)$$
implies the condition:
$$y'(t)x(t) = y(t)p(t)x(t) \iff y'(t) = p(t)y(t) $$

Answer (score 2):

It works because this example is very carefully chosen. Its structure then allows even a solution without integrating factor, at least in the construction of the particular solution. Apply the double-angle identity to get
$$
y'(x)=\sin(x)(y(x)+2\cos(x)).
$$
Set $u(x)=y(x)+2\cos(x)$. Then
$$
u'(x)=y'(x)-2\sin(x)=\sin(x)(u(x)-2),
$$
which is separable and implies
$$
u(x)-2=(u(0)-2)e^{1-\cos(x)}\implies y(x)=2(1-\cos(x))+y(0)e^{1-\cos(x)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by $e^{\cos x}$,

$$(y'-y\sin x)\,e^{\cos x}=(y\,e^{\cos x})'=\sin 2x\,e^{\cos x}.$$

Then by parts,

$$\int\sin x\cos x\,e^{\cos x}dx=-\cos x\,e^{\cos x}+\int\sin x\,e^{\cos x}dx=-\cos x\,e^{\cos x}+e^{\cos x}+c.$$

Answer (score 1):

Solve
$$y'=y \sin x\tag{1}$$
$\frac{y'}{y}=\sin x\to \log y=-\cos x +C\to y=ke^{-cos x}\tag{2}$

$$y'-y \sin x=\sin 2x\tag{3}$$

Then guess $y_p=a\cos x+b\to y_p'=-a\sin x$ and plug into $(3)$
$$-a\sin x -(a\cos x+b)\sin x=2\sin x \cos x$$
$$-(a+b)\sin x -a\sin x \cos x  =2\sin x \cos x$$
therefore must be $a=-2;\;b=2$ and $y_p=-2\cos x +2$

General solution to $(3)$ is
$$y=ke^{-cos x}+2-2\cos x$$